# Sorting drop down menus when changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a page that builds drop down menus dynamically from the database as follows:

```
<select name="set_order[]" class="form-control" data-catid="3">
    <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="set_order[]" class="form-control" data-catid="2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="set_order[]" class="form-control" data-catid="1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="">3</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is that when one of them is changed, I want to resort the drop downs according to the change that was made with Javascript and update the selected dropdown in each dropdown so as that each drop down has a unique choice made.

I've been trying to sort them but I haven't been successful.

Thank you in advanced!

Edit, as requested, here is my trial JS to sort them:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="set_order[]"]', function(){
    var newOrder = $(this).val();
    var change_id = $(this).attr('data-catid');

    console.log(newOrder, ' ', change_id);

    var order = new Array();
    var cat_id = new Array();

    var checker = false;
    $('select[name="set_order[]"]').each(function(i){
        order[i] = parseInt($(this).val());
        cat_id[i] = parseInt($(this).attr('data-catid'));

        console.log(order[i], ' ', cat_id[i], ' ', i);

        if(checker == false){
            if(cat_id[i] == change_id){
                checker = true;
            }else{
                order[i] = order[i] + 1 ;
            }
        }else{
            order[i] = order[i] - 1;
        }

        //console.log(order[i], ' ', cat_id[i], ' ', i);
    });


});
```

Comment: How have you been trying to sort them? can you show us?

Comment: @Adjit yeah let me post my JS

Comment: Ok, so can you explain how you want to sort it a little clearer? You want to resort all the other `set_order[]` but, how do you want that sorting to work?

Comment: @Adjit so when a drop down is changed to a different value, I want to sort the values selected by the rest of the drop downs so that each drop down is updated accordingly.

Comment: Right, but how do you want to sort it? A-Z? numerical order? Based on some value?

Comment: $adjit, so for example, the top drop down has the number 1 selected. If I change it to have number 2 selected, which the second drop down has, then the second drop down should now have number 1 selected.

Comment: What you want to sort then in which order clear this thing;

Comment: if I change dropdown one to have number 3 selected, then dropdown 2 should have number 1 selected, dropdown 3 should have number 2 selected. I hope that helps explain better.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to have anything to do with sorting.  It's more a variation of "cascading drop downs".

Comment: @Roberto well I do plan to update the database side and redisplay them sorted ascending after the javascript does its thing. Hence, I need some help figuring out the Javascript side :)

Comment: So your sorting is probably right, but you never actually sort the elements inside the DOM, just in the JS. You need to look at dom manipulation now

Comment: @Adjit, since I was doing console.logs on my sorting I could tell that I was not doing it right, that's why I didn't start updating the DOM.

Comment: You also realize that in order to select an option you don't need to sort it? You can simply change the selected value. So I'm still a little unclear of what you want to "sort"

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with jQuery

```
//Sort alphabetically the contact list in the biography page
function sortList() {
//Replace #list by the id of the div who enclose your select
    $("#list").html(
        $(".form-control").children("option").sort(function (a, b) {

            return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare(

            $(b).text().toUpperCase());
        })
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The only problem is that my drop downs are made based on the records in the database and I'm trying to update multiple drop downs, not just one.